# Keycloak as broker to another keycloak as idp and using curl

Tags: keycloak

I configured keycloak1 as identity-provider and keycloak2 as broker.

Was also able to connect them.

But I try to get a token for a user of keycloak1 via curl. But it does not work. I thought, it can pass it through as a kind of proxy?

Does ist only work with browser redirection or can I configure the broker to passthrough my request to the identity-provider and get the token from it?

thanks!